# Python list of tuple pairs: extract the first element based on nearest second element

Tags: python

Really a beginner at this:

I have a list: ((0.1, 5.4), (0.2, 5.6), (0.3, 6.0)) etc...
With a user input: 5.7

I would like to extract the nearest 'first element', in this case it should be 0.2.

How can I go about this?

EDIT: I guess this is called a tuple containing pairs.

Comment: Is the array sorted by the value on the second element?

Comment: You need to sort the sequence and then use a search function -- which you may want to write yourself.  It appears that you have some tutorials to work through.

Comment: @Prune you are right. I have a lot to learn..I'll do more research and post back

Comment: Great!  Try it out! Make glorious mistakes! Perhaps work through an appropriate tutorial or three.  When you get stuck on an honest attempt, *then* you'll have a good post for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function receives a key parameter, that can be used as a **key** to search for the mininum value:

```
value = 5.7
result = min(((0.1, 5.4), (0.2, 5.6), (0.3, 6.0)), key=lambda x: abs(value - x[1]))
print(result[0])
```

**Output**

```
0.2
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Would this be a good method if the list/tuple contains thousands of data?

Comment: The complexity of the method is O(n), so yes I believe it will me a good method, without further information is hard to tell if there is a better approach.

Comment: I'm running MIL (model in the loop) simulations, and the results are being stored as tuple containing pairs. There are hundreds of these tuples. In order to access a specific timestep, I pass a result value, your solution would give me the timestep. I use this timestep to access other results at that timestep in different tuples. Hope this clarifies.